# overlapping of surfaces with holes

Tags: statistics, probability

I have two disks, of equal diameter. Both disks have a 'spatter' of holes, in random positions (from a two-dimensional - i.e., surface -  uniform distribution; in other words, holes close to the sides are as likely to happen as holes close to the center). The number of holes per disk is normally distributed; holes' diameters are normally distributed, too.

If I overlap the two disks, some holes will (even partially) overlap; in other words, if I have a source of light beneath them, I will see light coming through the overlaps (possibly none, of course); it goes without saying that that percentage will change if I rotate the disks with respect to each other, from a minimum to a maximum.

I'm interested in the statistical distribution of the percentage of overlapping holes with respect to the surface of one disk. In particular, what will be the probability of having *less than* a certain percentage of overlap if I take two disks at random, and I measure separately their total surface of holes?
To fix the idea: let's say disks A and B have holes accounting for 25% and 35% of their surfaces, respectively; clearly, the maximum overlap will be 25%. If I overlap them at a random angle, is there a theoretical way to predict that the overlap will be less than a given value, say, 10%?

I suspect that the answer comes from Gaussian Random Fields, but I'm definitely not sure.

many thanks in advance for your suggestions and insights.
Kind regards,
Luca